# Ionic 3: Android Emulator throws Runtime Error: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined

Tags: ionic3, mapbox-gl-js

Got an unresolved Issue, that i can not handle.
Using MapBox GL with Ionic 3 and running it with Chrome works fine.
But Android Emulator throws an unexpected Runtime Error

See here
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6693

Does somebody have or had the same behaviors like this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Looks like Android Emulator is not supporting WebGL

`Error: Failed to initialize WebGL
    at n._setupPainter (mapbox-gl.js:32)`